# onActivityResult not called on facebook sign in

Tags: android, callback, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have an android app with facebook sign in.I initialized facebook sdk in a fragment.But the onActivityResult was never called when launching sign in procedure.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getContext());
        FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signin, container, false);
        gButton=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.loginGmail);
        fButton=(LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.loginFacebook);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        fButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        gButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity() /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        fButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Success"+loginResult.getAccessToken(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

But onActivityResult called when google sign in initiated.

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I got my answer.
I forgot to add

```
fButton.setFragment(this);
```

> For fragments this `setFragment(this);` method is required. Refer
>   [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android).

Comment: This is Very Helpful ! I tried a lot of hours till see this answer, Thank you for posting this answer !!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you Integrating facebook in Fragment to get result in fragment onActivty result you have to call it from Activty OnActivity result Like

[check this image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf7gb.png)

you this code in your activity OnACtivity result before super call you will get your result in fragment onActivity result Hope this help

Comment: What do you mean by YourFragment ?.Please show some examples.

Comment: Yourfragment means the fragment u r using for integration

Comment: I mean Yourfragment=myFragment.class; is it like that?

Comment: Yes... that exactly i mean if that you not understand yet tell me the name of fragment and tag of fragment

Comment: My fragment name is Signin.class. how to get tag from fragment? :)

Comment: or the tag is that which you used to replace fragment in FragmentManager  it may be like this                                   FragmentManager mFm=getSupportFragmentManager();                                                  mFm.replace(R.id.container,fragment,"tag");           if you not you tag when replace fragment than use it and get fragment by that tag